# Multiple fields in single array element using Vuejs

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

How will I add two or three fields from one row in a single array element in Vue? 
**Vue**

```
Vehicles: [
   "BMW 100 1994",
   "Audi 300 2001",
   "Toyota 200 2000",
   "Mazda 104 2011",
   "Car 104 2014",
   "Car2 140 2015" ]
```

Response

```
axios.get('/api/manage/manage/vehicles').then(response => {
        this.vehicles = response.data.vehicles;
      })
```

Database

[image]

Comment: It makes no sense to limit yourself like that. Vue is perfectly capable of working with an array of objects.

Comment: Actually i am adding this autocomplete from buefy.  I am new to VueJs. So please if you eplain to me. Thanks

Comment: https://buefy.github.io/#/documentation/autocomplete

Comment: aren't data supports array of objects?

     data Options / suggestions Array<String>, Array<Number>, Array<Object>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented already vue can handle arrays, or any other type as data.

But to answer your question, assuming that `vehicles` data from server is an object like:

```
console.log(response.data.vehicles)
[
  {id: 1, make: 'BMW', model: '100', year: 1994},
  {id: 2, make: 'Audi', model: '1 Series M', year: 1994}
]
```

To resolve this to your expectations you could do:

```
axios.get('/api/manage/manage/vehicles').then(response => {
  this.vehicles = response.data.vehicles.map(car => `${car.make} ${car.model} ${car.year}`);
})
```

See the above snippet to test how this is done:

```js
const vehicles = [{
    id: 1,
    make: 'BMW',
    model: '100',
    year: 1994
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    make: 'Audi',
    model: '1 Series M',
    year: 1994
  }
]

const output = vehicles.map(car => `${car.make} ${car.model} ${car.year}`)
console.log(output);
```